# Laravel custom guard not working once user logs in

Tags: php, laravel, routes

I have a custom login controller that is meant to set a custom guard depending on a users access level, which will determine what they can access on the site.

the login works, however when i add middleware to protect the routes, it returns null and i'm not sure this is the correct way to set the guard based on the user login.

currently the code just loops back to the login page, and the custom guard returns null.

```
// loginController.php
    if (Auth::attempt($request->only('email', 'password'))) {
         Auth::login(Auth::user(), true);       
         $this->guard('custom_user');
         return redirect('/home');
    }

    protected function guard($custom_user){
        return Auth::guard($custom_user);
    }

// config/auth.php 
    'guards' => [
        'custom_user' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],
    ],
    'providers' => [
       'users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\User::class,
       ],
    ],

// middleware/RedirectIfAuthenticaed.php
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if (Auth::guard('custom_user')->check()) {
            return $next($request);
        }
        return redirect('/login');
    }
```

*** UPDATE ***

I fixed the issue, was because i was setting secure cookies, but working on a local environment. Both solutions worked, just needed an SSL.

Comment: What you're describing sounds like authorisation and not authentication

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Auth::attempt` and `Auth::login` in your LoginController will use the default guard defined in `config/auth.php`. You have to specify which guard they should use.

And your `$this->guard('custom_user')` on its own will not do anything because it only returns a Auth instance.

Change your default guard to `custom_user` or change this in your Controller:

```
if ($this->guard('custom_user')->attempt($request->only('email', 'password'))) {
     $this->guard('custom_user')->login(Auth::user(), true);
     return redirect('/home');
}
```

Comment: So the problem seems to be in the middelware. when i implement this code, and do a `dd(Auth::guard()->check());` it returns true, then as soon as it hits the middle-ware the same check returns false.

Answer (score 0):

in your LoginController

```
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class LoginController extends Controller
{
    use AuthenticatesUsers;
    protected $redirectTo = '/home';

     public function login(Request $request)
     {
      $this->validate($request, [
        'email'   => 'required|email',
        'password' => 'required|min:6'
      ]);

      if (Auth::guard('custom_user')->attempt(['email' => $request->email, 'password' => $request->password])) {     
        return redirect('/home');
      }else{
         return redirect('/login');
      }

    }

}
```

in middleware/RedirectIfAuthenticated.php

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if (Auth::guard('custom_user')->check()) {
            return $next('/home');
        }
        return redirect('/login');
    }
```